# How to handle conditions written in 2D array

Tags: c++, algorithm, matrix

Consider this 2D array:

```
  A B C D E
A 1 0 0 0 0
B 0 1 1 0 0
C 0 1 1 0 0
D 0 0 0 1 1
E 0 0 1 1 1
```

This means that A *can be* mapped with A but sureshot can not be mapped with B, C, D or E.

Similarly, B *can be* mapped with B and C but not with A, D and E.

Here can be means that it might be mapped or not not be.

Now, I have to write an c++ code to make sure that this mapping holds and assert if it does not.

I have written an if else code about that like this(skeleton). I am checking the conditions where B should not sure shot matched.

```
if (checking_for_B) {
  if (B is mapped with A || B is mapped with D || B is mapped with E) {
    assert();
  }
}
```

Similarly, I would have to write the if condition for A, B, C, D and E as well. I am not happy with this approach. If you were me, what would you write?

Comment: [`assert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/assert) is a preprocessor macro that might expand to just a space (typically happens in release builds). And when enabled it *crashes* the application, so it's not very nice to end users.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, True that. And I want it to crash. :)

Comment: If you want the program to "crash" then either call [`abort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/abort) directly, or better yet throw a specialized exception (with a nice `what` message).

Comment: You probbaly want `assert(0);` or something like `assert(B is mapped with A || B is mapped with D || B is mapped with E)`. Also be aware of the previous comment.

Comment: The row for E shows that it can be mapped with C. But the row for C shows that it cannot be mapped with E. Is that intentional?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would try to solve your problem by turning the letters into row and column indexes, and check if that combination is allowed.

Then you don't need "checking_for_A" followed by "checking_for_B" etc. Just something like

```
if (my_map[row_letter_index][column_letter_index])
{
    // All okay, allow
}
else
{
    // Not allowed, report or abort or throw exception or anything else
}
```